# Connecting MySQL in a php file and using it in another php file

Tags: php, mysql, insert, connection, record

I have a config.php file such as

```
<?php
/**
 * Database config variables
 */
define("DB_HOST", "blabla");
define("DB_USER", "blabla");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "blabla");
define("DB_DATABASE", "blabla");

?>
```

And I have a connect.php file such as

```
<?php

class DB_Connect {

    // constructor
    function __construct() {

    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // $this->close();
    }

    // Connecting to database
    public function connect() {
        require_once 'config.php';
        // connecting to mysql
        $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        // selecting database
        mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);

        // return database handler
        return $con;
    }

    // Closing database connection
    public function close() {
        mysql_close();
    }

} 
?>
```

And I have a functions.php file such as

```
      <?php

    class DB_Functions {

        private $db;
    //put your code here
    // constructor
        function __construct() {
            include_once 'connect.php';
        // connecting to database
            $this->db = new DB_Connect();
            $this->db->connect();
        }

    // destructor
        function __destruct() {

        }

    /**
     * Storing new user
     * returns user details
     */
    public function insertRecord($name, $email, $gcm_regid, $password) {


        // insert user into database
        $response = array();
        $query0 = "SELECT * FROM gcm_users WHERE name='$name'";
        $result0 = mysql_query($query0);


        if(mysql_fetch_array($result0) == NULL){

    //insert...
            // insert user into database
  $query = "INSERT INTO `gcm_users`(`id`, `gcm_regid`, `name`, `email`) VALUES (NULL,'$gcm_regid','$name','$email');";

  $result= mysql_query( $query);
        // check for successful store
        if ($result) {
            // get user details
      //      $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gcm_users WHERE name = '$name'") or die(mysql_error());
            // return user details
      //      if (mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
                $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "record added";
    // echo no users JSON
        return $response;

    }else{
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No records added";
    // echo no users JSON
        return $response;
    }



}else{
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Record already exists";
    // echo no users JSON
        return $response;
    }

}
?>
```

And I have a simple function that inserts a record but it doesn't work.I think the multiple file connection system has an error transfering the connection but I couldn't find why .Please help me thanks.
By the way I call this method from another file
which includes and calls this method as

```
 include_once 'functions.php'; 
 $db = new DB_Functions();
 $res = $db->insertRecord($name, $email, $gcm_regid, $password);
        echo json_encode($res);
```

Sorry for misleading but I use this connection through an android application and the program is always entering the else part rather than if($result) part.However when I connect without using another config.php and connect.php and just writing everything in the same file as

```
       <?php

    class DB_Functions {

        private $db;
    //put your code here
    // constructor
        function __construct() {
            include_once 'connect.php';
        // connecting to database
            $this->db = new DB_Connect();
            $this->db->connect();
        }

    // destructor
        function __destruct() {

        }

    /**
     * Storing new user
     * returns user details
     */
    public function insertRecord($name, $email, $gcm_regid, $password) {
       $con = mysql_connect("blabla","blabla","blabla");
  mysql_select_db('blabla');


        // insert user into database
        $response = array();
        $query0 = "SELECT * FROM gcm_users WHERE name='$name'";
  $result0= mysql_query( $query0 , $con);


        if(mysql_fetch_array($result0) == NULL){

    //insert...
            // insert user into database
  $query = "INSERT INTO `gcm_users`(`id`, `gcm_regid`, `name`, `email`) VALUES (NULL,'$gcm_regid','$name','$email');";

  $result= mysql_query( $query , $con);
        // check for successful store
        if ($result) {
            // get user details
      //      $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gcm_users WHERE name = '$name'") or die(mysql_error());
            // return user details
      //      if (mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
  mysql_close($con);

                $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "products found";
    // echo no users JSON
        return $response;

    }else{
  mysql_close($con);

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No products added";
    // echo no users JSON
        return $response;
    }



}else{
  mysql_close($con);

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Product already exists";
    // echo no users JSON
        return $response;
    }

}
?>
```

the $result is returning true and the record is added.In fact there is not error , the situation that the $result variable doesn't turn to be true when I use object oriented connection pattern.

Comment: which error do you get?

Comment: in case of an error, always post it!

Comment: There is not error , the insert query does not work.Is there a possiblity that  `$this->db->connect();`  method is not enough to maintain the MySQL connection.Thanks for concern

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment... anyway...

According to [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php), "This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future." Consider using PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php.

Also, consider checking the connection and database selection with something like this:

```
$con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if(!$con) 
{
  die(“Connection issue: ” . mysql_error());
}


$db_selection=mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
if(!$db_selection) 
{
  die(“Database selection issue: ” . mysql_error());
}
```

*mysql_select_db will use the last connection opened with mysql_connect() if you don't pass in the connection you want to use as a second parameter. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

After changing your DB information to suit my test environment, it worked fine so I don't think $this->db->connect(); is the issue. I'd double check that the right DB and table information is being used. Hope this helped a bit... new here.

Also your functions.php file you posted is missing a: `}?>`. Do you have error reporting turned on? Might want to check that the DB_Functions instance is even being made.

Comment: Thanks for your help but but the DB and table informations are right because record is added or not according to the insertRecord method's structure,I changed the codes a little bit they are the same as my InsertRecord before and after versions.First version doesn't work but second works.That is the issue.Missing brackets are due to the copy paste.Can you please again check what is going on there ?

Comment: Hmm so in the first case, $result doesn't return true... even though the record is added? 

I copied the code (and added the extra `}` in functions.php, and made a gcm_users table just to make sure. In both cases the code works like it should. Are you defining the same information in the config.php that you are using to connect in the second function.php?

Try checking what mysql_error() returns to see if it gives any hints when $result doesn't return true. Otherwise I wish I could be of more help, sorry!